# how to get items in a list of tuple based on the value in tuple

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, tuples

I get a combined list of data and sorted it using zip function

```
comb_list = sorted(zip(score_list, move_list), key = lambda pair: pair[0], reverse = True)
```

the out put is something like this

```
a = [(3, (5, 4, False)), (3, (6, 4, False)), (2, (5, 1, False)), 
(1, (6, 2, False)), (-1, (6, 2, False))]
```

I want to sort by the first element in tuple (in list), find the maximum value, and output the second element in tuple. Here the max value is 3, and the output will be

```
[(5, 4, False), (6, 4, False)]
```

or if I have

```
a = [(3, (5, 4, False)), (2, (5, 1, False)), (1, (6, 2, False)), (-1, (6, 2, False))]
```

and the output will be

```
[(5, 4, False)]
```

Comment: Why do you want to sort if you're just finding the max?

Comment: You obviously know how to use a `key` function with `sorted`, since you're doing that in your existing code. And if you can write `pair[0]` you surely must know how to write `pair[1]`. So… what part of this are you stuck on?

Comment: sorry, actually I am new to python... I can only get (5, 4, False), not [(5, 4, False), (6, 4, False)], though it also have the maximum key.

Comment: OK, so [edit] the question to write as much as you know how to write, and then explain where you're stuck, instead of making us guess at that. The reason you're getting a bunch of bad answers is that your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

There are more efficient ways to do this than sorting the whole list and then filtering, but since you've already sorted the whole list by key, and presumably understand how that works, let's start there:

```
a = [(3, (5, 4, False)), (3, (6, 4, False)), (2, (5, 1, False)), (1, (6, 2, False)), (-1, (6, 2, False))]
```

So now, you want to filter it on just the ones whose key is the same as the top one:

```
b = [(key, value) for key, value in a if key == a[0][0]]
```

… except that you just want the `value`, not the `(key, value)` pair, which is simple:

```
b = [value for key, value in a if key == a[0][0]]
```

---

Now, why is this inefficient? Well, if you've already sorted the list, you don't really need to check *every* value; you can break out of the loop as soon as you find one that doesn't match (e.g., with `itertools.takewhile`). But, more simply, you don't need to sort in the first place; just get the `max`, and then use that to filter:

```
comb_list = list(zip(score_list, move_list))
comb_max = max(comb_list, key=lambda pair: pair[0])
b = [value for key, value in comb_list if key==comb_max[0]]
```

Or, even better, you don't even need to build an intermediate list, because the `max` doesn't need the `zip` in the first place. Which also makes things a lot simpler to understand:

```
max_score = max(score_list)
b = [move for score, move in zip(score_list, move_list) if score == max_score]
```

Answer (score -3):

A very simple and pythonic way to solve it

```
>>> max_value = max(a, key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
>>> max_value
3
>>> [x[1] for x in a if x[0]==max_value]
[(5, 4, False), (6, 4, False)]
```

you can use max built-in method with key :

```
 >>> a = [(3, (5, 4, False)), (3, (6, 4, False)), (2, (5, 1, False)),
... (1, (6, 2, False)), (-1, (6, 2, False))]
>>> max([(x,list(y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])], key=lambda x:x[0])
(3, [(3, (5, 4, False)), (3, (6, 4, False))])
```

Comment: This isn't the OP's desired output.

Comment: Updated my post, have a look

Comment: But the new version isn't the OP's desired output either.

Comment: @abarnert do you want me to mouth feed the OP,  i got the values, any one can simple extract now.

Comment: When someone is confused about how to get the first value of each pair in a list, giving him an answer that still requires him to do exactly the part he's asking how to do is not very helpful. Replacing the part he _does_ know how to do with something more efficient (but more complicated) is nice, but it doesn't answer his question.